# How to remove last character of a number in C#

Tags: c#, substring

This is my string "codes 02 - UFL 1500"

```cs
String SelCurItem;                      
String GradeGSM;
Int32 CalcLengthSelCurItem;
Int32 CalcLengthGradeGSM;

CalcLengthSelCurItem = SelCurItem.Length - 11; //this part gives me the first 8 characters back
GradeGSM = SelCurItem.Substring(11, CalcLengthSelCurItem); // gives me "UFL 1500" BACK
CalcLengthGradeGSM = GradeGSM.Length - GradeGSM.IndexOf(" ");
Grade = GradeGSM.Substring(0, GradeGSM.IndexOf(" ")); // GIVES ME "UFL" back
GSM = Convert.ToInt32(GradeGSM.Substring(GradeGSM.IndexOf(" "), CalcLengthGradeGSM)); // GIVES ME "1500"
```

Now i want to add another field named GSM2 and i want the output to give me back "150" it must drop the last character. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Use [`string.SubString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: i tried to convert the GSM ToString and then remove the last character but didnt work out

Comment: How about dividing GSM by 10 .

Comment: If it's an int you can simply divide it by 10...

Comment: @m.rogalski GSM is an Int32

Comment: Divide by 10 as others suggested `var lastWord = Convert.ToInt32(("codes 02 - UFL 1500").Split(' ').Last().Trim());
  var output = lastWord/10;` or in case the last word is not a number always, then, `var lastWord = ("codes 02 - UFL 1500").Split(' ').Last().Trim();  
  var output = lastWord.Substring(0, lastWord.Length - 1);`

Comment: If `GSM` is between 0 and 9 do you want it to result in an empty string? Or is it impossible for GSM to be between 0 and 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either:

```
Int32 GSM2 = GSM1/10;
```

or

```
Int32 GSM2 = Int32.Parse(GSM1.ToString().Remove(GSM1.ToString().Length -1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't code in C#, but you can divide by 10. And since it is an int type it won't have a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**UPDATED**

```
String GSM2 = GSM.ToString().Substring(0,GSM.ToString().Length-1);
```

Assuming that you obtain GSM2 throw GSM, you can take GSM and discard the last caracter

Comment: `GSM` in question is of type `int`. And as far as i know `int` doesn't have `Substring()` method.

Comment: GSM is an int23. It doesn't have the Substring method.

Comment: Seems such a lot of effort when String GSM2 = (GSM / 10).ToString() would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex to split the whole string (and get the last number without the last digit):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<FirstPart>.{8}) - (?<SecondPart>.{3})\s(?<Number>\d*)(?<LastDigit>\d)");
var match = regex.Match("codes 02 - UFL 1500");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["FirstPart"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["SecondPart"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Number"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["LastDigit"].Value);

// Output:
// codes 02
// UFL
// 150
// 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Substring

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String s = "aaaaabbbcccccccdd";
      Char charRange = 'b';
      int startIndex = s.IndexOf(charRange);
      int endIndex = s.LastIndexOf(charRange);
      int length = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
      Console.WriteLine("{0}.Substring({1}, {2}) = {3}",
                        s, startIndex, length, 
                        s.Substring(startIndex, length));
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       aaaaabbbcccccccdd.Substring(5, 3) = bbb
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx